# Search a string for a word/sentence and print the following word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string that has around 10 lines of text. What I am trying to do is find a sentence that has a specific word(s) in it, and display the word following.

**Example String:**

> The quick brown fox
>
> The slow donkey
>
> The slobbery dog
>
> The Furry Cat

I want the script to search for 'The slow', then print the following word, so in this case, 'donkey'.

I have tried using the Find function, but that just prints the location of the word(s).

**Example code:**

```
 sSearch = output.find("destination-pattern")
        print(sSearch)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `string.replace` @dwb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output = "The slow donkey brown fox"
patt = "The slow"
sSearch = output.find(patt)
print(output[sSearch+len(patt)+1:].split(' ')[0])
```

output:

```
donkey
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work with regular expressions. Python has builtin library called [re](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html).

Example usage:

```
s = "The slow donkey some more text"
finder = "The slow"
idx_finder_end = s.find(finder) + len(finder)
next_word_match = re.match(r"\s\w*\s", s[idx_finder_end:])
next_word = next_word_match.group().strip()
# donkey
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using regular expressions (`re` module) following way:

```
import re
txt = '''The quick brown fox
The slow donkey
The slobbery dog
The Furry Cat'''
words = re.findall(r'(?<=The slow) (\w*)',txt)
print(words) # prints ['donkey']
```

Note that `words` is now `list` of words, if you are sure that there is exactly 1 word to be found you could do then:

```
word = words[0]
print(word) # prints donkey
```

Explanation: I used so-called *lookbehind assertion* in first argument of `re.findall`, which mean I am looking for something behind `The slow`. `\w*` means any substring consisting of: letters, digits, underscores (`_`). I enclosed it in group (brackets) because it is not part of word.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> r=re.compile(r'The slow\s+\b(\w+)\b')
>>> r.match('The slow donkey')[1]
'donkey'
>>>
```